# Decorator Pattern in C++ with templates

Tags: c++, templates, design-patterns, variadic-templates

I am trying to understand this example from a pluralsight video (that I've modified a little):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

//this next line is partial specialization, but I don't understand why it's necessary
template<typename> struct Logger;

template <typename R, typename... Args>
struct Logger<R(Args...)>
{
    std::function<R(Args...)> func_;
    std::string name_;

    Logger(const std::function<R(Args...)>& func, const std::string& name):
        func_{func}, name_{name} {}

    R operator() (Args... args)
    {
        std::cout << "Entering " << name_ << std::endl;
        R result = func_(args...);
        std::cout << "Exiting " << name_ << std::endl;
        return result;
    }
};

// this is how the example was originally written.  It uses a function pointer as an argument which is ok except you can't give it a lambda.  
template <typename R, typename... Args>
auto make_logger(R (*func)(Args...), const std::string& name) ->Logger<R(Args...)>
{
    return Logger<R(Args...)>{std::function<R(Args...)>(func), name};
}

//this is my attempt to make it so it will accept a lambda but it doesn't work.
template <typename R, typename... Args>
auto make_logger2(std::function<R(Args...)> func, const std::string& name) ->Logger<R(Args...)>
{
    return Logger<R(Args...)>{std::function<R(Args...)>(func), name};
}

double add(double a, double b, double c)
{
    std::cout << a  << " + " << b << " + " << c << " = " << a + b + c << std::endl;

    return a + b + c;
}

int main()
{

    auto logged_add = make_logger(add,"Add");
    auto result = logged_add(2,3,5);

//    auto lm  = [](std::string str1, std::string str2){return str1 + str2;};
//    auto logged_string = make_logger2(lm, "string add");
//    auto result2 = logged_string("Hello ", "World!");

    //I get the following compile error if the next two lines are uncommented:
    // main.cpp:101: error: no matching function for call to 'make_logger2(main()::<lambda(std::__cxx11::string, std::__cxx11::string)>, const char [11])'

    //auto logged_string = make_logger2([](std::string str1, std::string str2){return str1 + str2;},"string add");
    //auto result2 = logged_string("Hello ", "World!");

    std::cout << "result = " << result << std::endl;
    //std::cout << "result2 = " << result2 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

My main two questions are why is the partial specialization and is it possible to modify the code so it can take a lambda as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why is the partial specialization?

The intent is to provide a function type, but also get out of it return type and types of the arguments.
You can do that only with a partial specialization, that is the following one:

```
template<typename> struct S;

template<typename R, typename... Args>
struct S<R(Args...)> { /* ... */ };
```

As you can see, the primary template doesn't have a definition, for it's not required at all in this case.
Anyway, note that it accepts only one type. The intent is to use it as it follows: `S<void(int, char)>`.
How could you know that the return type is `void` and `int` and `char` are your parameters in the primary template? You cannot, but you do within the specialization.

> is it possible to modify the code so it can take a lambda as well?

You can even get rid of `std::function`s and function pointers, so as to have a lambda-only based solution. Using lambdas you can easily capture or invoke the other functions.

Here is a minimal, working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <typename F>
struct Logger: F
{
    std::string name_;

    Logger(F &&func, const std::string& name):
        F{std::move(func)}, name_{name} {}

    template<typename... Args>
    auto operator() (Args&&... args)
    {
        std::cout << "Entering " << name_ << std::endl;
        auto result = F::operator()(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        std::cout << "Exiting " << name_ << std::endl;
        return result;
    }
};

template <typename F>
auto make_logger(F &&f, const std::string& name)
{
    return Logger<std::decay_t<F>>{std::move(f), name};
}

double add(double a, double b, double c)
{
    std::cout << a  << " + " << b << " + " << c << " = " << a + b + c << std::endl;
    return a + b + c;
}

int main()
{
    auto logged_add = make_logger([](auto... args) { return add(args...); }, "Add");
    auto result = logged_add(2,3,5);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code will accept both function pointers and lambdas, where the variadic arguments are moved the operator() and the specialization is no longer needed.

```
template <typename Func>
struct Logger
{
    Func func_;
    std::string name_;

    Logger(Func&& func, const std::string& name):
        func_{std::move(func)}, name_{name} {}

    template<typename... Args>
    decltype(auto) operator() (Args&&... args)
    {
        std::cout << "Entering " << name_ << std::endl;
        decltype(auto) result = func_(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        std::cout << "Exiting " << name_ << std::endl;
        return result;
    }
};

template <typename Func>
decltype(auto) make_logger(Func&& func, const std::string& name)
{
    return Logger<std::decay_t<Func>>{std::move(func), name};
}
```

[live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bfce350e2835ccad)

Comment: You'll want to `std::move` that `Func` into storage in your make function.  For industrial quality, I would also write a converting ctor to Logger (where if `FuncA` is convertible to `FuncB`, so is `Logger<FuncA>` to `Logger<FuncB>`).  Also have make and Logger ctor take the string by-value and `std::move` it can save on allocations.

Comment: `decltype(auto) operator()` and `decltype(auto) result` will add support for return-by-reference.

Comment: oh I didn't know about auto/decltype(auto) diff, that's a good one to know :)